# SQLite and Visual Studio 2013 Update 3

Tags: entity-framework, sqlite, visual-studio-2013

After upgrading Visual Studio 2013 from Upgrade 2 to **Upgrade 3**, I can not anymore connect Entity Framework to SQLite database.

I have downloaded and installed **sqlite-netFx451-setup-bundle-x86-2013-1.0.94.0.exe** but it apparently dont work with VS 2013 Update 3!

In Server Explorer, Add Connection, there is item for "System.Data.SQLite Database File" but when I Add EF Model to project, and go to "EF Designer from database", then New Connection, there is no SQLite item in list ??!

How is possible to same "Chose Data Source" dialog in Server Explorer have SQLite option, and with EF connect to database that same dialog does not have SQLite option??

Comment: Because the current implementation is broken! Log an issue at http://system.data.sqlite.org